# Reindexing Quicktime file ... how?

Tags: quicktime

I have a video file (.mov > QuickTime) which was recorded with an HD camera.

One of the problems with this camera is that when the battery dies, it doesn't finalize the video file correctly... which is exactly what happened to my video. All the video and audio data should actually be there, but the .mov file is missing headers and should be reindexed.

Aeroquartet charges $80, and Grau GbR's HD Video Repair Utility charges $ too. There must exist a (free) tool which can simply reindex a .mov file, but I've yet to find it...

I'm on Mac OS Lion. I've tried MPEG Streamclip, but no success. I've tried VirtualDUB, but that doesn't work. Both refuse to load any non-indexed file, even though they claim to be able fix such. Can anyone suggest another tool or any other way to fix (reindex) QuickTime movies? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem as you and I tried GbR's demo tool, but it only recovered the sound. The video was recorded at 60 FPS and that didn't appear as an option in the program. The test fix at Aeroquartet looked promising. I think I am going to have to go that way although like you I think it's pricey for just 1 video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure this will work, but it's worth a try. If you "convert" the video with a program, such as [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php), to the same or another video format and that might fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! Tried Handbrake, but same thing...does not recognize video that is not indexed already.

Comment: Ah, sorry then, if I come across something else I'll let you know.